# how to refresh a google site using google apps scripts ?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

My site fetches chart from spreadsheet but it is getting updated only when it is refreshed manually. Publishing on web is not working as expected. So Any method to refresh a site is much appreciated.  Please do not include browser extensions or plugins or widgets, because of site audience.

Answer (score 2):

After some hours struggling with this, i found a solution that worked for me.
Place this code in Templated HTML file. Then call function `reloadSite()` in Javascript to reload current site.

```
<script>
  function reloadSite() {
    window.top.location.href = '<?!= SitesApp.getActivePage().getUrl(); ?>';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to end the onSubmit() with the function that calls the Ui. You state it is doGet(), like this :

```
function onSubmit(e){

// Your code ...
doGet();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate little further... My doubt is how to refresh a google site say for every 1 minute with a google script automatically. Here we do not Submit anything isn't ?

Comment: if you want a script to refresh your webpage every minutes , I think it not possible.  
you can update a webpage with  HTML services and you create a page with a DataBase ( Google Spreadsheet ). it's the other possibility.